# Is there a way to infer the types of a specific value from an interface passed as a generic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It's entirely possible that I'm approaching this incorrectly, since I'm new to TS, but I'm wondering if I have some generic type through which I will pass an interface that looks like `{[key: string]: string | boolean}` is it possible to know the type of any specific value inside the function that is consuming that generic.

For example, I have an interface like:

```
export interface Address {
    addressId: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    addressType: string;
    addressLine1: string;
    addressLine2: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    zipCode: string;
    email1: string;
    phone1: string;
    primary: boolean;
    nickName?: string;
}
```

and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function useForm<T>(initialValues: T) {
  const [form, setForm] = useState<T>(initialValues);

  const field = (key: keyof T) => {

    const setValue = (newValue: T[keyof T]) => {
      const newState = {
        ...form,
        [key]: newValue
      }
      setForm(newState);
    }
    const value = form[key];
    return {
      value,
      setValue
    };
  }

  return {
    form,
    field,
  };
}
```

My textField has an interface that looks like this

```
interface TextFieldProps {
  field: {
    setValue: (value: string) => void;
    value: string;
  };
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  containerStyle?: ViewStyle;
}
```

and in my form looks like

```
const {form, field} = useForm<Address>(someInitialAddress);
...
<TextField field={form("FirstName")} />
...
```

It's already throwing a type error if you try to load a field that doesn't exist on the interface, but I'd like to guard to make sure you aren't loading a boolean based value or something else into that field, and I'm getting this type error currently: 
`Type '{ value: string | boolean | undefined; setValue: (newValue: string | boolean | undefined) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ setValue: (value: string) => void; value: string; }'.`

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I may dig a bit deeper and follow up but just taking a quick look I will point out - when you start talking about the type of a "value", you are talking about run time and javascript - type information will be completely stripped away from the output. At run time, if you are guarding for the type of a value in a function, I'm pretty sure you're left with your standard run time type checking in JS (i.e., typeof)

Comment: @MrRobboto I think I get that, but it just seems unclear to me why that `form` function can know to make a union of the types in the interface as well as know all the keys in the interface, but there doesn't seem to be a way to say given this interface and key `foo` make sure the typecheck on the function you're returning matches that value's specific type.

Comment: Ah I see now you have a literal in there so nevermind about the run time stuff. I was just thrown off by the word "value" but totally makes sense for literals. I'm still trying to wrap my head around your problem, not totally following. I think `<K extends Extract<keyof T, string>>` may help you out though, shooting in the dark a bit. I've had to use that a few times doing generic stuff where I'm trying to say a parameter is of type K, that is a keyof T, and a string.

Comment: Still don't have a solid understanding of it though - TypeScript doc for it doesn't say enough IMO. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu

Comment: Oh, also relevant, what version of TS are you using? They changed keyof T in 2.9

Comment: Right at the top they talk about some big changes that seem relevant to this:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html

Comment: Mainly the question is given the useForm hook up there, can the type of the argument for the `setValue` function that gets returned be inferred to a specific type and not just a union of all the types in the generic.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coming up short. Just went through all the utility types that do type transformation and not seeing anything in there to do what you're saying. If I'm understanding right, you basically want to construct a type that is a subset of T, containing only properties of type string? A utility like `Subset<T, string>` so in your setValue you could do `<Subset<T, string>[keyof T]` ? Doesn't seem like it exists, would be really nice though. You could always just define another type that is a subset of T, or do a base type and use inheritance, etc.

Comment: Utility types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt

Comment: Here's an article implementing this on their own - it's old so maybe there's something in TypeScript now for it but doesn't look like it - but definitely there are some solutions out there it seems you could do even if TypeScript doesn't: https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c

Comment: ^Seems like a lot going on but they were able to achieve a nice syntax in the end and do like I was thinking: `SubType<Person, number | string>` as an example.

Comment: I think I found your answer, above totally worked for my testing - thanks for the challenge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this works for what I needed:

```
function useForm<T>(initialValues: T) {
  const [form, setForm] = useState<T>(initialValues);

  function field<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    function setValue<PropType extends T[K]>(newValue: PropType) {
      const newState = {
        ...form,
        [key]: newValue,
      };
      setForm(newState);
    };
    const value = form[key];
    return {
      value,
      setValue,
    };
  };

  return {
    form,
    field,
  };
}
```

When utilized like this:

```
interface Address {
    addressId: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    addressType: string;
    addressLine1: string;
    addressLine2: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    zipCode: string;
    email1: string;
    phone1: string;
    primary: boolean;
    nickName?: string;
}

...
const { field, onSubmit } = useForm<Address>(someInitialAddress);
...
<TextField
  field={field('firstName')}
  label="First Name"
  placeholder="First Name"
/>

This returns the field prop as:
field: {
  setValue(value: string): void;
  value: string;
};

...

<CheckboxField
  field={field('primary')}
  label="Use as my primary address for Billing and Shipping"
/>
This returns the field prop as:
field: {
  setValue(value: boolean): void;
  value: boolean;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe there is something more out of the box in TypeScript but it seems this problem has been solved with existing utility types.

Per this article: https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c

You can define a type for this like `SubType<T, A>` that will construct a new type with a subset of keys from type T, that are of type A. I'm pretty sure that's what you're looking for.

SubType Definition - this will assign type `never` to the properties that are not of type A so they will not be allowed for use and show compile errors, in intellisense, etc.

```js
export type SubType<A, T> = Pick<A, {
  [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends T ? K : never
}[keyof A]>;
```

And then you can use it like this in your case for the `setValue` function:

```js
const setValue = (newValue: T[keyof SubType<T, string>]) => {
  const newState = {
    ...form,
    [key]: newValue
  }
  setForm(newState);
}
```

Given the below interface `Test` - you should see the following type-checking behavior:

```js
export interface Test {
  stringKey: string;
  booleanKey: boolean;
  numberKey: number;
}

this.setValue(true); // Err true is not assignable to type string
this.setValue(5); // Err 5 is not assignable to type string
this.setValue('string'); // No Error
```

The only problem, is you can still pass NULL and Undefined without error. If you read comments in the linked article there are a few tweaks to the above solution that I think will handle that - I'll edit this if I find time.

Hope it helps - and thanks for the challenge!

Comment: I think maybe I still didn't explain what I'm looking to solve here. Unless I'm misunderstanding your solution. 

Given my example in the OP I'm mostly hoping that initializing like `const {field} = useForm<Address>(initAddress)` you could then get it to be like `form('firstName') => { setValue: (value: string) => void, value: string }` but also `form('primary') => { setValue: (value: boolean) => void, value: boolean }`

Comment: In your example `const setValue = (newValue: T[keyof SubType<T, string>]) => {` in my case I won't always know its a `string`

Comment: Then do `string | boolean` instead of just string. And you still want it to be a `keyof T` right? So you could do `const setValue = (newValue: T[keyof SubType<T, string | boolean>])`.

Comment: Oh and I guess you would also have to edit your `TextFieldProps` setValue function to be `string | boolean` or split it out like you did in your answer.